# Join filter panels as one

Tags: qliksense

Need to add Filter panels as a vizualation and combine it as one

[image: Sample Panels]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drag and drop fields together. Remember that auto suggester can set chart in such a scenario just change to Table. In table you can make selections of all fields together,

[image]